# Ограниченный трафик на VDS-хостинге

Tags: трафик, хостинг

Здравствуйте! Предполагаю, что вопрос из разряда "от блондинок", но жопаделать, если жизнь заставляет.

Ситуация следующая - на VDS-хостинге есть N-ное количество сайтов, хостинг будет меняться. На новом всё хорошо, но есть ограничение по трафику в месяц (*с чем я никогда не сталкивался, т.к. всегда трафик был безлимитным*): на планируемом тарифном плане составляет **4 Тб**. Так как я "чайник" в этих вопросах, то всё, на что меня хватило - это посмотреть статистику на текущем хосте в *Webalizer Stats*. Выбрал максимальные показатели каждого сайта за месяц, просуммировал и получилось около **25Гб**. С точки зрения нуба, 4Тб с головой хватит, но т.к. я родился еще при Советском Союзе, то предполагаю, что не всё так просто. Собственно вопрос в том, как определить наиболее достоверные данные по трафику на текущем хостинге, если Webalizer-а не достаточно и как определить будет ли хватать выделяемого трафика на новом хостинге?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно грубо посчитать так, объем сайтов на диске умножить на количество уников в месяц. Получится максимально возможный средний трафик, если он будет меньше 4Тб, то все ок. Но на самом деле можно исходить из того, что безлимитных тарифов на vds-ках не бывает, обычно мелким шрифтом написано ограничение, максимально я видел 5Тб. То есть если ты постоянно не отдаешь с сайта многомегабайтные файлы, то 4Тб тебе скорее всего хватит за глаза.